# Minimze effect on customized button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So here's is the situation:

I've created a custom button that minimizes my WPF application,

the thing is that it minimizes right away to the taskbar
 (unlike random applications that have the Win7 minimize effect).

My question is, how can I put that regular effect on my customized button when it minimizes?

Thank you.

Comment: My window is actually a rectangle, but let me know your suggestion please, I might implement it.

Comment: @Exsaliver Forgot to tag

Comment: is the window driven from a Window class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could P/Invoke [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to add the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, tho I changed my mind on doing it, I'd like to use the win32, regular close and minimize buttons on my app instead of using a customized button to do this job, do you have any idea how can I gain these buttons to be on a rectangle(WPF). Thanks again.

Comment: Well, again, no built in way. P/Invoke with DrawFrameControl http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Ehh, could you supply me a link with an example or something? I really don't know how I can implement it into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the Button Click event (the border cause the minimize animation)

```
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

override OnActivate to hide again the border what the window is maximized

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnActivated(e);
            if (WindowStyle != WindowStyle.None)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate(object unused)
                {
                    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                    return null;
                }
               , null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer tho I get a runtime error: it says that AllowTransprency must be true, when I do the following in the event: this.AllowTransparency = true; I'm getting another error, another thing is that the compiler doesn't know what is DispatcherPriority. Thank you.